# Error: Command failed: cscript.exe //Nologo

Tags: npm, electron, registry

We are using npm-regedit module to read/write registry in Windows. We are using it in an electron app. Normally when we run the application it works fine but when we set the app to run automatically at startup the regedit module fails. We get the following error on reading "HKCU/SOFTWARE":

Error: Command failed: cscript.exe //Nologo D:\CodeLathe\Workspace\cl-fc-client\clouddrive2service\ui\dist_electron\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\vbs\regList.wsf A HKCU\SOFTWARE

Comment: Unclear. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

copy the VBS folder (Store the directory of.wsf files) in the regedit package to your own directory.
Then customize the VBS directory :`regedit.setExternalVBSLocation('./common/vbs');`